# TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float32' has no len()

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I have had Tensorflow Lite running on a Raspberry Pi for a while to do some object detection, I have tried it on a few test models with no problems at all. Recently I tried to make my own model and I ran into this error. How can I fix this and does anyone know what is wrong with it?

This is my code for running Tensorflow Lite on my Pi

```
import os

import argparse

import cv2

import numpy as np

import sys

import time

from threading import Thread

import importlib.util



class VideoStream:

    """Camera object that controls video streaming from the Picamera"""

    def __init__(self,resolution=(640,480),framerate=30):

        self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        ret = self.stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'))

        ret = self.stream.set(3,resolution[0])

        ret = self.stream.set(4,resolution[1])

            

        (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()



        self.stopped = False



    def start(self):

        Thread(target=self.update,args=()).start()

        return self



    def update(self):

        while True:

            if self.stopped:

                self.stream.release()

                return



            (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()



    def read(self):

        return self.frame



    def stop(self):

        self.stopped = True



parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--modeldir', help='Folder the .tflite file is located in',

                    required=True)

parser.add_argument('--graph', help='Name of the .tflite file, if different than detect.tflite',

                    default='detect.tflite')

parser.add_argument('--labels', help='Name of the labelmap file, if different than labelmap.txt',

                    default='labelmap.txt')

parser.add_argument('--threshold', help='Minimum confidence threshold for displaying detected objects',

                    default=0.5)

parser.add_argument('--resolution', help='Desired webcam resolution in WxH. If the webcam does not support the resolution entered, errors may occur.',

                    default='1280x720')

parser.add_argument('--edgetpu', help='Use Coral Edge TPU Accelerator to speed up detection',

                    action='store_true')



args = parser.parse_args()



MODEL_NAME = args.modeldir

GRAPH_NAME = args.graph

LABELMAP_NAME = args.labels

min_conf_threshold = float(args.threshold)

resW, resH = args.resolution.split('x')

imW, imH = int(resW), int(resH)

use_TPU = args.edgetpu



pkg = importlib.util.find_spec('tflite_runtime')

if pkg:

    from tflite_runtime.interpreter import Interpreter

    if use_TPU:

        from tflite_runtime.interpreter import load_delegate

else:

    from tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter import Interpreter

    if use_TPU:

        from tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter import load_delegate



if use_TPU:

    if (GRAPH_NAME == 'detect.tflite'):

        GRAPH_NAME = 'edgetpu.tflite'       



CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()



PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,GRAPH_NAME)



PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,LABELMAP_NAME)



with open(PATH_TO_LABELS, 'r') as f:

    labels = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]



if labels[0] == '???':

    del(labels[0])





if use_TPU:

    interpreter = Interpreter(model_path=PATH_TO_CKPT,

                              experimental_delegates=[load_delegate('libedgetpu.so.1.0')])

    print(PATH_TO_CKPT)

else:

    interpreter = Interpreter(model_path=PATH_TO_CKPT)



interpreter.allocate_tensors()



input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()

output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

height = input_details[0]['shape'][1]

width = input_details[0]['shape'][2]



floating_model = (input_details[0]['dtype'] == np.float32)



input_mean = 127.5

input_std = 127.5



frame_rate_calc = 1

freq = cv2.getTickFrequency()



videostream = VideoStream(resolution=(imW,imH),framerate=30).start()

time.sleep(1)



while True:



    t1 = cv2.getTickCount()



    frame1 = videostream.read()



    frame = frame1.copy()

    frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    frame_resized = cv2.resize(frame_rgb, (width, height))

    input_data = np.expand_dims(frame_resized, axis=0)



    if floating_model:

        input_data = (np.float32(input_data) - input_mean) / input_std



    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'],input_data)

    interpreter.invoke()



    boxes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])[0] 

    classes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[1]['index'])[0] 

    scores = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[2]['index'])[0] 



    for i in range(len(scores)):

        if ((scores[i] > min_conf_threshold) and (scores[i] <= 1.0)):



            ymin = int(max(1,(boxes[i][0] * imH)))

            xmin = int(max(1,(boxes[i][1] * imW)))

            ymax = int(min(imH,(boxes[i][2] * imH)))

            xmax = int(min(imW,(boxes[i][3] * imW)))

            

            cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin,ymin), (xmax,ymax), (10, 255, 0), 2)



            object_name = labels[int(classes[i])]

            label = '%s: %d%%' % (object_name, int(scores[i]*100)) 

            labelSize, baseLine = cv2.getTextSize(label, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, 2) 

            label_ymin = max(ymin, labelSize[1] + 10)

            cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin, label_ymin-labelSize[1]-10), (xmin+labelSize[0], label_ymin+baseLine-10), (255, 255, 255), cv2.FILLED) 

            cv2.putText(frame, label, (xmin, label_ymin-7), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 0), 2) 



    cv2.putText(frame,'FPS: {0:.2f}'.format(frame_rate_calc),(30,50),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(255,255,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)



    cv2.imshow('Matthew De La Rosa: AP Research 2021-2022', frame)



    t2 = cv2.getTickCount()

    time1 = (t2-t1)/freq

    frame_rate_calc= 1/time1



    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):

        break



cv2.destroyAllWindows()

videostream.stop()
```

This is my error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TFLite_detection_webcam.py", line 137, in <module>
    for i in range(len(scores)):
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float32' has no len()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

```
boxes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[1]['index'])[0] 

classes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[3]['index'])[0] 

scores = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])[0]
```

hope this will fix your problem

Comment: I am sure it would help the community if you explained to us why your code would solve the OP's problem

Comment: Because the output order of model is changed . I notice this by converting tf1 and tf2 object detection to tflite and then i checked output details using
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

Comment: I had the same issue, and this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

`score` is of type `numpy.float32` and so cannot be passed to `len()` but can instead be passed directly to `range()` if it can be converted to an int

```
for i in range(int(scores)):
```

if this is not possible it may be that scores is supposed to be a `list` and the issue lies earlier in the code

Comment: I can try this, I just don't see why it would be giving me this error on my custom model and not every model. 

Will still give this solution a go.
Thank you.

Comment: if you have referance code to go off i would check what data type scores is supposed to be at that point

Comment: My project is based off of this tutorial

https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Lite-Object-Detection-on-Android-and-Raspberry-Pi

len() is what was originally used.

Comment: your code does seem to be set up for scores to be a list, however `scores = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[2]['index'])[0] ` is returning a float not a list

Comment: I see. So how would I fix this?

Comment: `interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[2]['index'])[0]` is selecting just the first element of a list returned by `get_tensor()`, maybe try just `scores = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[2]['index'])`